# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict' leaderboard command error

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a leaderboard command in my bot. It's supposed to show the top 10 people. I am currently getting this error when I run the command.

`TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'`

My current code for the leaderboard command is:

```py
@bot.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Top 10 {ctx.guild.name} leaderboard:", color=discord.Colour.gold())
    with open('cookiecount.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    sorted_data = {id: bal for id, bal in sorted(data.items(), reverse=True , key=lambda item: item[1]['cookiecount'])}

    for pos, (id, bal) in enumerate(sorted_data.items()):
        member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(id))
        embed.add_field(name=f"{pos+1} - {member}", value=f"{bal} cookies", inline=False)
        if pos+1 > 9:
            break 
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Inside `cookiecount.json` file:

[image]

Comment: What is the full traceback? `<` is not used anywhere in the code you provided.

Comment: What's in your `cookiecount.json`?  Sounds like you need to be pulling the scores out of there instead of trying to sort the raw blobs.  (I assume the error is being thrown by the `sorted` call because it's comparing dicts.)

Comment: @It_is_Chris: `sorted` would perform `<` to compare the computed keys. If the values of `data` are themselves `dict`s, that would cause the problem.

Comment: @It_is_Chris Edited my question with it

Comment: @Samwise Edited my question with it

Comment: It helps if sample data is posted as text not picture - that way we can cook up our own tests with a simple copy/paste.

Comment: `key=lambda item: item[1]` is causing the problem. It returns the second element of `cookiecount.json`, which is a dict itself.

Comment: This is a good question but because it doesn't come with a runnable script, its not as useful to future readers as it could be. Since most of the code you post is unrelated to the problem you could replace it with a few lines that use `json.loads` to load your sample data and then a line that does the sort. It would have the same error but it would be more apparant for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the data out of the JSON for something specific you have to use the following:

```py
sorted_data = {id: bal for id, bal in sorted(data.items(), reverse=True , key=lambda item: item[1]['cookiecount'])}
```

Comment: Side-note for the OP: The `dict` comprehension (both here and in your original code) is a no-op, so you'd be better off replacing it with the `dict` constructor, e.g. using the fixed code in this answer: `sorted_data = dict(sorted(data.items(), reverse=True, key=lambda item: item[1]['cookiecount']))`, which is both more succinct and faster to boot.

Comment: @ShadowRanger When I try that, I get, `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ColeTMK'`

Comment: @ColeTMK: Sounds like your input data isn't what you said it was. The error you're seeing would come later on, and be a result of invalid inputs, not related to the sorting you're doing (correctly or incorrectly). It's entirely unrelated to the problem in your question.

Comment: @ColeTMK Did you replace it with the right values? My first answer was incorrect, had `exp` in it instead of `bal`. Maybe you also want to replace the output with `{bal['cookiecount']}` to just display the number.

Comment: @ColeTMK: And you just edited the question and put in entirely different inputs, which would definitely have this problem. You can't keep changing the question parameters, while concealing information, and expect to get a useful answer.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I decided to change my json file from the author's id to the author's name. I think that is why I was getting the error.

Comment: Now I am confused. It works fine for me if I follow the tutorial you were looking at. I just used `member.mention` in the embed. Just work with the ID as this is unique and you will be fine.

Comment: @Dominik I changed it to your answer put this is what the embed looks like.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdNDi.png

Comment: @ColeTMK See one of my comments... "*Maybe you also want to replace the output with `{bal['cookiecount']}` to just display the number.*" (Even though this has nothing to do with your question anymore!)

Comment: @Dominik I edited it like this, `sorted_data = {id: bal for id, bal in sorted(data.items(), reverse=True , key=lambda item: item[1][{bal['cookiecount']}])}` but get error, `NameError: free variable 'bal' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope`

Comment: @ColeTMK These are now already errors that should not be dealt with in the comments, ask a new question for that even though the error tells you what is wrong. The problem could be solved apparently (see comments with your screenshot) and now I don't understand what you are doing.